# Could hidden text be made to allow code formatting?

Tags: feature-request

Could hidden parts of posts be made to support code highlighting/indentation and quote formatting?

Currently when you hide some text with `>!` code indents and quotes are not recognized:

E.g.

```
>! > supposed to be some quote
```

results in:

> > supposed to be some quote

And

```
>!    if {2-3} `=` -1:
>!        cd /random/dir
```

results in:

> if {2-3} `=` -1:
>         cd /random/dir

I can't think of much of a use for quotes, but code formatting could provide an option for users to try and figure out stuff on their own, and only read example code if they get stuck.

Comment: Spoiler markup strips out alignment so I doubt this is possible without some hacking.. `<br />` and `&nbsp;` etc. It works to an extent but the code appears dark. This also seems to be a bit trivial _IMO_. Isn't the point of asking for code to view it?